# How to show the entire time format along the key row in RedisInsight-v2?

Tags: redis

[RedisInsight-v2](https://redis.com/redis-enterprise/redis-insight/) only shows a single unit time along the row. For example, if the key's Time to Live is bigger than one hour, then the minutes and seconds are not displayed along the row. This way, the only option to see the entire time is to hover on the time value and get a Time to Live box. So is there any option to show the complete time format?

[image: Time to Live box]